# Rectangle with Gradient Color in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am using anchorpane in my javafx application. I want to draw a rectangle and fill it with gradient color like this: the left side of the rectangle is blue and the right side is red and I want it to seem that from left to right, the blue color decreases and red color increases.

I know how to put a rectangle ( how to use the Rectangle class in javafx ) but I don't know how to fill it this way. Any ideas?

Comment: `setFill(new LinearGradient(...))`? See [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: gradient]

See [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/LinearGradient.html) on linear gradients.

```
public class Gradient extends Application {

    public static final double S = 100;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Stop[] stops = new Stop[] {
                new Stop(0, Color.BLUE),
                new Stop(1, Color.RED)
        };
        LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(
                0, 0,
                1, 0,
                true,
                CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
                stops
        );

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(S, S, gradient);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(rectangle)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you also provide code for this question? I want to add a mouse click option that removes some part on the right side of the rectangle. ( width = 10, height = S ) 
So that there will be more blue color left in the rectangle after deletion of the right side.

Comment: @NaturalQuestioner Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  If you are still having issues with your additional requirement, please include a new question with an [mcve] (a complete, minimal, self-contained example which somebody could copy and paste to run without change) which illustrates the issue you encountered developing a solution, then somebody will likely assist you.

Comment: @NaturalQuestioner If this answer is a correct answer to your original question, please mark it as such.

Comment: Yes, it was! Thank you.